# laravel 5 optimize whereHas by replacing with Join

Tags: mysql, join, laravel-5, eloquent, where-clause

I have a vehicle listing page with filters. I have created a scope for applying the selected filters to the vehicles table. The scope make use of eloquent whereHas method. But it has serious performance issues while executing query because I see each whereHas is converted to subqueries instead of Join. See my scope function below and the query run

```
public function scopeApplyFilter($query, $conditions, $featured=0)
{

    $query->where(function($q) use ($conditions){
        if ($conditions->get('content')) {
            $q->where('text', 'like', '%'.$conditions->get('content').'%' );
        }
        if ($conditions->get('condition')) {
            $q->where('condition', $conditions->get('condition'));
        }
        if ($conditions->get('transmission')) {
            $q->where('transmission', $conditions->get('transmission'));
        }
        if ($conditions->get('price')) {
            $range = explode('-', $conditions->get('price'));

            $q->where('price', '>=',$range[0]);
            $q->where('price', '<=',$range[1]);
        }
        if ($conditions->get('odometer')) {
            $range = explode('-', $conditions->get('odometer'));

            $q->where('odometer', '>=',$range[0]);
            $q->where('odometer', '<=',$range[1]);
        }
        if ($conditions->get('year')) {
            $range = explode('-', $conditions->get('year'));

            $q->where('year', '>=',$range[0]);
            $q->where('year', '<=',$range[1]);
        }

        return $q;
    })->whereHas('model', function($q) use ($conditions) {
        if ($conditions->get('model')) {
            $q->where('model_name', $conditions->get('model'));
        }
        return $q;
    })->whereHas('make', function($q) use ($conditions) {
        if ($conditions->get('make')) {
            $q->where('make_name', $conditions->get('make'));
        }
        return $q;
    })->whereHas('dealer.province', function($q) use ($conditions) {
        if ($conditions->get('province')) {
            $q->where('province_name', $conditions->get('province'));
        }
        return $q;
    })->whereHas('dealer', function($q) use ($conditions, $featured) {
        if($featured){
            $q->where('featured', 1);
        }
        if ($conditions->get('lat')) {
            //$conditions->put('distance',5000);
            $lat = $conditions->get('lat');
            $lon = $conditions->get('lon');
            $lat = 53.421879;
            $lon = -113.4675614;
            $q->select(DB::raw("id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($lon) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance"))->having('distance','<',$conditions->get('distance')); //3959 for miles
        }
        return $q;
    });
}
```

The query run is

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `vehicles` 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   `models` 
               WHERE  `vehicles`.`model_id` = `models`.`id`) 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   `makes` 
               WHERE  `vehicles`.`make_id` = `makes`.`id`) 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   `dealers` 
               WHERE  `vehicles`.`dealer_id` = `dealers`.`id` 
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                  FROM   `provinces` 
                                  WHERE  `dealers`.`province_id` = 
                                 `provinces`.`id`)) 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT id, 
                      ( 6371 * Acos(Cos(Radians(53.421879)) * 
                                    Cos(Radians(latitude)) * 
                                    Cos( 
                                                  Radians(longitude) 
                                                  - Radians( 
                                                  -113.4675614)) 
                                    + 
                                             Sin(Radians(53.421879)) * 
                                             Sin(Radians(latitude))) 
                                 ) AS 
                      distance 
               FROM   `dealers` 
               WHERE  `vehicles`.`dealer_id` = `dealers`.`id` 
               HAVING `distance` < 200) 
   AND `status_id` = 1 
ORDER  BY `created_at` DESC 
LIMIT  15 offset 0
```

> 501.16 ms

I am using Laravel 5.2. Make, model and dealer are 'belongsTo' relation of vehicle. Everything works fine. But due to performance issues I am forced to rewrite the function using joins. Guys, please help with a best practise to rewrite this function using joins based on conditions like given above. Your inputs are most welcome.

Comment: Are all columns indexed correctly?

Comment: Shall I just index all the columns used in queries in the vehicles table or any specific pattern to index?

Comment: There are approx 25k vehicles, 1k dealers, 60 makes, 1k models. Which is not big. I think using eloquent for large db cause bottlenecks. Better not rely on eloquent relation functions they provide? Or may be use it for simple relation queries only.

Comment: I would at least make sure all of your `*_id` columns are indexed and (assuming they're never going to be negative) also add `unsigned` as well.

Comment: Done. Mot much improvement. around 475ms now.

Comment: I could be mistaken but exists should be more efficient than using joins. Have you already tried using joins manually? If so, what were the performance increases?

Comment: Issue with join in the dealers section when used with db raw and having. It says "unknown column distance".

Comment: $query->join('dealers', 'vehicles.dealer_id', '=', 'dealers.id')->select(DB::raw("dealers.id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($lon) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance"))->having('distance', '<', $conditions->get('distance'));